# How can I edit CVSROOT in all Jenkins jobs by modifying the config.xml files?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have a lot of jobs in Jenkins and we have to update `CVSROOT` in all of them. Is there any way to do update all the jobs at once using config.xml rather than updating every job individually?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs in Jenkins are represented by xml files on the master. you can just run a quick shell script for search and replace in files for each *.xml in the /jobs folder on your master.